# Power BI Comparative sales report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I have to prepare a stacked column chart with two bar. One will be fixed - Last day of last financial year. Another will show latest date when not selected. Alternately, I want to select from date slicer drop down with any previous date of current year and compare it with last FY end date Sale. So, when the date will be changed in slicer, it will only change one bar, while last FY bar should remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

It could be better if you provide some more details with your current approach..

**If I have to guess then you probably you need 2 measures,**

> 1. Create a Measure which dynamically calculate last year FY last date Fact (Sales, Inventories etc...)
> 2. Create a Measure which is using current year date to calculate (This has to be same date or related date which you are considering
>      for your slicer)

Then you can use these 2 measure values in Stack chart,
Remember your first measure remains static throughout current year but second measure change as per your date selection.

I hope it helps!!